# Create a community user from a person record

Tags: customer-community, user, person-accounts

Is it possible to create a community user from a person account?  Traditionally I’ve done this with contacts.

Comment: did you read: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_create_external_users.htm&type=5 ?

Comment: I just did.  I was looking for something like that.  Seems that the limitation is 50000 community members can be made from them.  Then they can’t be partner members.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you just need to populate user.ContactId with the personAccount.PersonContactId on insert.